# Replace all the dots in a number

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to replace all dots found in a value entered by the user in an HTML form.
For instance I need the entry '8.30' to be converted to '8x30'.

I have this simple code:

```
var value = $(this).val().trim(); // get the value from the form
value += ''; // force value to string
value.replace('.', 'x');
```

But it doesn't work. Using the console.log command in Firebug, I can see that the replace command simply does not occur. '8.30' remains the same.

I also tried the following regexp with no better result:

```
value.replace(/\./g, 'x');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: value.replace(/\./g, 'x'); is correct and its working for me [I've checked in firbug console e.g.
"2312.88.12.1232".replace(/\./g, 'x');

Comment: @Chinmayee: yeah it works indeed. As pointed out by Bart Kiers (below), I just forgot that it would not automatically update the value in my variable.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`replace` returns a string. Try:

```
value = value.replace('.', 'x');   //
                                   // or
value = value.replace(/\./g, 'x'); // replaces all '.'
```

Comment: That was too obvious. ;)
Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

You have three solutions:

```
var text= "ABC.DEF.XYZ";
response = text.replace(/\./g,'x');


var text= "ABC.DEF.XYZ";
response = text.replace(new RegExp("\\.","gm"),"x");


var text= "ABC.DEF.XYZ";
response = text.split('.').join('x');
```

[DEMO in JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YP3KW/605/)